# Node.js, ошибка при компиляции через pkg

Tags: node.js, компиляция, библиотеки, require

После компиляции и запуска Node.js приложения через `pkg` вижу ошибку в консоли:

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1244
      throw error;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module './src/cat'
Require stack:
- C:\snapshot\myappe\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js
- C:\snapshot\myappe\index.js
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:15)←[39m
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1346:46)
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1087:19)←[39m
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1225:31)
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)←[39m
    at C:\snapshot\myappe\node_modules\←[4mshelljs←[24m\shell.js:25:3
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\myappe\node_modules\←[4mshelljs←[24m\shell.js:24:23)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1320:22) {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\snapshot\\myappe\\node_modules\\shelljs\\shell.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\snapshot\\myappe\\index.js'←[39m
  ],
  pkg: ←[33mtrue←[39m
}
```

Причём для её воспроизведения достаточно только лишь одного подключения библиотек:

```
const figlet = require("figlet");
const shell = require("shelljs");
```

Модули переустанавливал, толку тоже никакого не дало. Что я делаю не так? :(

Comment: тебе нужно выложить минимальный восспроизводимый пример, который мы сможем запустить. если ты хочешь чтоб тебе помогли

Comment: ну и, кроме того, если создать bare-проект, поставить figlet и shelljs, написать index.js `const figlet = require("figlet"); const shell = require("shelljs"); console.log(figlet); console.log(shell);` и собрать командой `pkg -t node14-macos-x64 index.js` - **всё собирается и сборка запускается**

Comment: а если напрячься и создать скрипт, который действительно будет собираться, но валиться при сборке, то всё легко решаемо если добавить рекомендуюмую секцию с `"pkg": {
    "scripts": [],
    "assets": [
      "node_modules/figlet/fonts/Ghost.flf",
      "node_modules/figlet/fonts/Standard.flf"
    ]}`

Comment: 4 issue, в которых написаны варианты решения https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues?q=figlet+is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed